Issues Arising After Codesigning an Application (.app File)
I am codesigning an application (.app file) using the following command.
codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose --strict --deep --sign "$DEVELOPER_ID_APPLICATION" --options runtime --timestamp "${installerFile}"
The codesign process completes without any issues. However, the .app file stops working after it is code-signed. Specifically, the file does not open as expected.
If I remove '--options runtime' the codesigned application opens without any issues. However the notarization fails with an error: The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.
I am using xcode 14.3.1. The variables used in the above command are correct. I am codesigning the application to notarize it using notarytool.

you sure about that --timestamp argument? shouldn't it be a URL? or omitted?

When I omit the '--timestamp' flag during notarization, I encounter an error during notarization stating 'The signature does not include a secure timestamp.' Even when I remove the '--timestamp' flag and successfully code sign the installer, it still refuses to open. The installer only opens when I exclude the '--option runtime' flag, but this causes the notarization process to fail.
